# Where do we encounter sequence of infinite events of which we would like to study probabilities?

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have come across sequence of functions and numbers in the context of approximation theory and understand that a lot of theory of functional analysis came out with the idea to approximate solutions to partial differential equations.

In what contexts have people been curious to study/develop the theory of sequence of events - tossing of coin an infinite number of times or in some limit are not somethings I believe would motivate these kind of pursuits.

Do some mathematicians and others who use probability have a practical context to share in this kind of system modelling with properties of increasing, decreasing, countability, uncountability of sequences of events and their probabilities come into picture?

Comment: Brownian motion (and hence, many other stochastic processes) can be constructed from a countable sequence of coin flips by constructing a piecewise continuous paths, normalising appropriately and then taking limits. This is known as Donsker's Invariance Principle. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker's_theorem). I don't understand what you're asking because structured sequences of events are ipso facto described and studied via stochastic processes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Well I asked this question because I was taught some aspects about sequences of events as a part of the probability theory lectures in my stochastic processes class. I was really wondering where does this need of defining sequences of events arise form. I guess Brownian motion and Donsker's theorem should give good insights.

Comment: You may want to look at discrete martingales. A good reference with several in-depth examples is Khoshnevisan's *Probability*.

Answer (score 1):

There are very many applications of stochastic processes.  To name a few, gambling, statistical sampling, insurance, communication networks, stock option pricing.

Comment: I was looking for sequences of events in particular, stochastics surely has applications. I am looking for ideas that demand assuming sequences of events - specially infinite ones and uncountable ones.

Comment: Sequences of events arise in all these areas.